# Problem to dispaly content in pdf file

Tags: wordpress, pdf, dompdf

I am using dompdf for my wordpress project. I have to generate the certificate for user that I have created with my own table. Now I have to generate the pdf with the user information that i have saved in table. PDF is generated and saved but when I open the pdf file, this message is displayed " **Adobe Reader could not open 'certificate.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)** ". But when I use the same code out of the wordpress, it works perfectly. I have installed dompdf in folder www\project\wp-content\themes\mysite .

Can anyone help me out how to make PDF work.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the Wordpress generated PDF file also contains the HTML content of the page. I've seen applications that send a PDF file to browser and then in the same stream they send also the HTML page content and this damages the PDF.

Open the PDF file with Notepad and if you see any HTML content, either at the beginning or at the end, then you found the problem.

Comment: Thank you Sorin.. You helped me .. I used ob_clean(); before ob_start();. It worked for me .. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: I'm glad I solved your problem, please do not forget to mark the question as answered. Thanks.